# React hooks - Dynamically adding and deleting component. Delete problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

**CODESANDBOX LINKE PROVIDED!**

**Short summary of the app's idea:**
Online exam app contains two components: examform, and question. and a context component: exam.
examform contains all of dynamically added questions by user.
User can also DELETE questions. Each question has a unique id.

**The intended functionality:**
The questions are stored in the exam context array to be accessible by examform and by question.
So the idea here is, once the user clicks delete button of a question, that question will be removed from the context array by using its id, and thus reflect the change on examform component.

**The problem:**
Let's say user added 3 questions.
If the user clicks delete on the 2nd question, the 3rd question will be deleted instead and the second question will have the 3rd question's id. If he clicks on 1st the second will be deleted instead.
The weirder part is, the user clicks on delete on the last question (say 3rd) that exact question will be deleted.

All I want is to delete the question which user clicks on without disturbing the other elements of the array.

Please check out the code first before making assumptions, thanks.

[CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-poincare-7g4qr)

I changed the original code and questions just to make it simple and removed most of the styling just for demo purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems

1. The radio group name on each question requires a unique "name" attribute since the selection of any radio item on any question would affect another.

solution: append the id prop value to the name attribute to create unique name group per question

```
<input type="radio" name={`sport_${id}`} value="soccer" />
```

2. The logic for removing a question from the questions should not reside in the question itself.

possible solution: Provide a method to which the card calls with its id to remove itself from the array (see code below)

3. The rendering of your items was a little weird. Rather store the data in an array, and deal with rendering in the return method. **dont forget your key** prop otherwise your selection will be lost (best to store this in state too)

exam.js

```
export const ExamProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  const removeQuestion = (id) => {
    setQuestions((questions) => questions.filter((q) => q.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <Exam.Provider
      value={{
        questions,
        setQuestions,
        removeQuestion
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Exam.Provider>
  );
};
```

Question.js

```
const Question = ({ i, id}) => {
  const { removeQuestion } = useContext(Exam);

  return (
    <div className="q-main">
      {id}
      <div className="q-title">
        <h4>Which sport are you interested in the most?</h4>
        <div className="options">
          1. Soccer
          <input type="radio" name={`sport_${id}`} value="soccer" />
          2. Basketball
          <input type="radio" name={`sport_${id}`} value="basketball" />
          3. Bjj
          <input type="radio" name={`sport_${id}`} value="bjj" />
          4. MMA
          <input type="radio" name={`sport_${id}`} value="mma" />
        </div>
        <div className="name">
          Write your name:
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="delete">
        <button className="deletebtn" onClick={() => removeQuestion(id)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

ExamForm.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Exam } from "../contexts/exam";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import { IoIosAddCircle } from "react-icons/io";
import Question from "./Question";

const ExamForm = () => {
  const exam = useContext(Exam);

  const addQ = () => {
    const id = uniqid();
    exam.setQuestions((questions) => [
      ...questions,
      {
        id: id
      }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-main">
      <button onClick={addQ} className="addqcs">
        <IoIosAddCircle className="addicon" size={65} color="#0089d6" />
      </button>
      {exam.questions.map((q) => {
        return <Question key={q.id} i={exam.questions.length + 1} id={q.id} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExamForm;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-snowflake-575qs?file=/contexts/exam.js)